# Java and and or operator not working

Tags: java, operators, conditional-statements

I am using the following statement to break out of the loop when two conditions met:

```
while (true)
    {
        if (uAnswer1.equals(answerB1) || uAnswer1.equals(answerB2)
                || uAnswer1.equals(answerB3)|| uAnswer1.equals(answerB4) 
                &&
                uAnswer2.equals(answerS1)|| uAnswer2.equals(answerS2)){
            break;
        }
```

The loops breaks when one or both && conditions are met. However, I wrote the code to break the loop ONLY when both conditions are true.

Is there something missing from above statement?
Regards,
Shei7141.

Comment: above code shows that `uAnswer1.equals(answerB4) &&     uAnswer2.equals(answerS1)` are in `AND` condition

Comment: In this case the `&&` will take precedence over the `||`. @JigarJoshi has the correct answer.

Comment: Are `answerBn` and `answerSn` values constant while in the loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wrap them in parentheses

```
if ( (uAnswer1.equals(answerB1) || uAnswer1.equals(answerB2)
                || uAnswer1.equals(answerB3)|| uAnswer1.equals(answerB4))
&&
(uAnswer2.equals(answerS1)|| uAnswer2.equals(answerS2)) )
```

or

even make a `HashSet` of correct answers and do this will be clean and will be efficient too

```
answers1Set.contains(uAnswer1) && answers2Set.contains(uAnswer2)
```

Answer (score 0):

above code shows that **uAnswer1.equals(answerB4) && uAnswer2.equals(answerS1)** are in **AND** condition

```
while (true)
    {
        if ((uAnswer1.equals(answerB1) || uAnswer1.equals(answerB2)
                || uAnswer1.equals(answerB3)|| uAnswer1.equals(answerB4)) 

                &&

                (uAnswer2.equals(answerS1)|| uAnswer2.equals(answerS2))){
            break;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

while (true)
    {
        if ((uAnswer1.equals(answerB1) || uAnswer1.equals(answerB2)
                || uAnswer1.equals(answerB3)|| uAnswer1.equals(answerB4))
                &&
                (uAnswer2.equals(answerS1)|| uAnswer2.equals(answerS2)))
            break;
        }